# Integrable and continuous of two variables function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

$f(x,y)$ is integrable (Riemann or Lebesgue) on $D=[a,b]\times [c,d]$, 
let $I(y)=\int_a ^bf(x,y) dx$,

Can we get the conclusion $I$ is continuous on $[c,d]$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Lebesgue integral, setting that $f(x,y)=\chi_{{\bf{Q}}\cap[0,1]}(y)$, we have $\displaystyle\int_{[0,1]^{2}}f(x,y)dx\times dy=0$ and that $I(y)=\displaystyle\int_{[0,1]}\chi_{{\bf{Q}}\cap[0,1]}(y)dx=\chi_{{\bf{Q}}\cap[0,1]}(y)$ is certainly a discontinuous function on $[0,1]$.

For Riemann integral, the answer is still no. Simply assume $f(x,y)=\chi_{[0,1/2]}(y)$, the similarly argument works and one has $I(y)=\chi_{[0,1/2]}(y)$.

Comment: Good, how about Riemann integral?

Comment: I cannot understand your Riemann integral part, why $f(x,y_{n})\rightarrow f(x,y_{0})$ as $n \to \infty$

Comment: In fact, for Riemann integral, the answer is still no. Simply assume some jump function with variable $y$, such that $f(x,y)=1$ on $[0,1/2]$ and $0$ on $(1/2,1]$, $x$ is free here, the similarly argument works and deduce that $I$ is this jump function.

Comment: So, one can see that if $f$ is continuous with respect to $y$ (with $x$ fixed), then your assertion is valid, the reason is that, the pointwise convergence with respect to $y$ is then valid, as what I have wrote (and overthought) just now.